# Illustrator: Selecting all objects across x axis

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, illustrator-scripting

Ok so I got this huge document, about 1.5 x 1.2 metters and because I was working a little bit fast the aligning of some elements wasn't pixel perfect but is more or less accurate. 
Now that I've finished setting all this elements I want to align them so they are all placed correctly. The problem I'm experiencing now is that the elements are too small so when I zoom out to select them is not really easy and most of the times I select elements that I don't want to select.

Here is a zoomed example of the document, what I want is to select all pink dots and allign them with the blue one. Nothing really difficult with align tool the problem is the size of the document itself.

[image: zoomed in image]

But when I zoom the whole document out this is what I get.

[image: zoomed out image with guides]

and without guides it seems this way

[image: zoomed out image without guides]

I belive this could be achieved via scripting, but I don't know so much about it. What I want is for example select a blue dot and then run a script for selecting everhing that matches its y position so I can just align to that key object.

Edit: What I need to do is something like this.

Imagine I have a selection like this one 
[image: step 1]

And I want to expand it only in x position through all the document like this one
[image: step 1]

The distributing horizontally is great but vertically they are not correctly aligned. Blue ones are in place but some red/pink ones are missplaced by some pixels and need to fix that. I hope this clarifies a little bit the question

Any help will be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you define "aligning" to the "blue dot" more precisely? Vertical or Horizontal align? Distribute Objects? Distribute spacing?

Comment: I've edited the question so I believe is more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. draw a rectangle with the Rectangle Tool (M)
   [image]
2. change the transformation "anchor" proxy to the Middle Left
3. change the width of the box you drew in step 1 to enclose all of your art
   [image]

[image]

4. with the rectangle still selected, go to Object->Artboards->Convert to Artboards
5. then go to Select->All on Active Artboard
   [image]

Comment: I just ended up with a new dilema. Is it possible to select all on active artboard ONLY if the center of the shape is present on current artboard? This is because sometimes the circles are too close and I end up selecting some I didn't want to select.

Comment: sorry but no, this method selects everything it touches, I would Shift+Click the circle I don't need selected.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing but is kinda slow. Once again thank you for the answer and now I have a lot of steps to do.

Comment: once you make the first rectangle, make a copy of it, and move down to the next row, before converting it to artboard, that'll be one step less to do.

Comment: is this a one-off project? or something you do all the time? I think the whole project could be scripted

Comment: This is actually a one-off project. I made plenty of copies of the same rectangle so now I have them all vertically aligned. The process was not that hard but now I have to do it horizontally and I will end up with more or less 400 artworks to do this alignment. I'm not a graphic designer, I'm a musician and wanted to do this keyboard chord poster containing almost 1600 chord variations. I belive aligning them all will take me a month and probably more because I'm doing it just on my free times. Here is a little part of the project zoomed in. http://i.imgur.com/lqLCEiR.png

Comment: I also noticed if I shrank the rectangles I end up with less unwanted selections but I still have to check them because I don't want to mess the correct positions just align them a little bit so it looks professional. I really thank you for your interest on this project, I thought nobody would ever answer the question

Comment: you're welcome, well not bad for not being your field, if I come up with something else I'll post here...I like your work, my favorite is Technology, and Take off, and Far Away From Here, and That's Love, and...

Comment: I'm glad to hear you liked my work. That means a lot to me, thanks for listening. And please if you come up with something don't hessitate on posting it here, any ideas are welcome